# Openstack network access

Tags: networking, cloud, ubuntu-18.04, openstack, devstack

I am trying to install openstack on a single node server.
I need to access Instances from internet.
I am new to openstack, so I spent some time trying to get it work correctly but without success. I tried devstack but it is not persistent after reboot.
For microstack, it is not configurable.

I need to assign Public IPs to instances. I have 2 physical networks. I tried with external network, but I don't found an option how to do that.

Did anyone successfully installed openstack on a single machine, and is there a way to expose instances to bring them puclic IPs from a pool.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes I have used Devstack countless times and added floating IPs to instances. By default, Devstack creates its own "external network", which is not external at all, but it can be attached to the true external network in your datacenter or lab. **What is your problem?** You say "without success" - can you state what "success" means to you, and how your attempts fail?

Comment: Devstack is not meant to be rebooted. The two main configuration items that are not persistent are the external bridge and the loop devices used for implementing Cinder's volume groups. It is not very hard to set them up after rebooting. Hoping this is not considered illegitimate advertisement of my blog entry, here is one solution: https://itnext.io/a-single-server-devstack-cloud-as-a-kubernetes-platform-cd30e28e405a#8acc. Note that it also sets up Neutron load balancers and netfilter rules for Magnum, which you may not be interested in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @berndbausch . This will help me for bringing up the lost setup after reboot. My problem is that I don't find a way to assign a fixed public IP to an instance. I need this to access my instances from the internet.

Comment: The Devstack setup on the same blog page does this. The main secret is configuring a non-default external subnet range, and to insert the NIC that is connected to the internet into br-ex.